# Problem parsing RSS with a PHP script

Tags: php, rss, xml-parsing

im using a very common php script to parse RSS;

```
function getRSS($source,$quien) {
    $start = microtime(true);
    ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 1);
    global $arrFeeds, $downItems, $time_taken;
    $arrFeeds = array();
    $ch = curl_init($source);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($content);
    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $itemRSS = array ( 
            'title' => sistema($node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue),
            'desc' => sistema($node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue),
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue
        );
        echo(sistema($node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue)."<br>");
        array_push($arrFeeds, $itemRSS);
        $downItems+=1;
    }
    $time_taken = microtime(true) - $start;
    if ($downItems>1) {$nu=mysql_query("UPDATE feeds SET lastcheck = NOW() WHERE id = '".$quien."';");}
}
```

When i test this code with the [rss news feed](http://news.google.it/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=it&hl=it&output=rss) from google it works just fine, but if i try it with this [other rss feed](http://rss.jobsearch.monster.com/rssquery.ashx?rad_units=km&cy=it&pp=15&occ=11900&occ=11728&occ=11737&occ=11715&occ=11788&occ=11746&occ=11747&occ=11786&occ=11782&occ=11980&occ=11838&occ=11825&occ=11867&occ=), it wont work, and gave A LOT* of errors like; *Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: P line 5 and BODY in Entity, line: 6 in C:\Users\Domingo\Dropbox\www\temp\parser.php on line 18*. The two above rss files ARE valid, the only different i found between are that one of those have the line: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and the other no. Is this the problem? And how can i solve this? Thanks for any help, and PLEASE do not suggest to use an rss parser libary.

(*) more errors like: `Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: BODY line 3 and HTML in Entity, line: 6 in C:\Users\Domingo\Dropbox\www\temp\parser.php on line 18`
and `Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Premature end of data in tag HTML line 1 in Entity, line: 7 in C:\Users\Domingo\Dropbox\www\temp\parser.php on line 18`

Comment: Your code won't run standalone so it's difficult for someone else to debug it. I suggest you compose a simplified version and update the question with it.

Comment: The parser complains about XML elements P and BODY, which are not present in the feed. Perhaps the data retrieved by the script is different from the data retrieved by a browser. Are you sure the script has XML to parse?

BTW, the feed validator from W3.org does not consider the second feed valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second feed itself looks fine and does not contain and body or p tags. You're probably mixing things up and are loading the wrong file.