# RSS - Opening and ending tag mismatch - WHY?

Tags: rss, cdata

I've been trying to debug my RSS feed with little success.  I keep getting the same error, whatever I change in it.

"error on line 18 at column 61: **Opening and ending tag mismatch**: copyright line 0 and title"

You can view the feed here: http://www.dico2rue.com/feed.php

I've seen other posts, but they don't seem to answer my question, including:
[Problem parsing RSS with a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519038/problem-parsing-rss-with-a-php-script)

Am I getting the CDATA wrong?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing your closing `>` from your CDATA tag. A simple View Source from Firefox shows the problem in its XML syntax coloring.

Comment: I hate these mistakes, I've been looking at it for 45min... Thanks @Mark Thomas.